# I could not discover transaction status

Tags: gwt, jboss

I started my war file on jboss, and i am getting this error when I try to log in my web application on jboss.

```
Error [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] could not discover transaction status.
```

What should i do ?

Comment: What did you find googling it ?

Comment: i solved my problem, i cleared the temp folder, it started to work normal.

Answer (score 0):

i just cleared the temp folder on jboss folder directories.